# Where can I get a yoo slider to use in PHP?

Tags: php, joomla

At the bottom side of this page http://www.pilabsbd.com/new/index.php#page, there is a yoo slider. I found a Joomla version of the slider in net. 
Can anyone please tell me where I can find the version to use in php just as the site above has done?

Comment: Let's see: Joomla is a PHP framework. YOOslider is a Joomla module. What makes you think that YOOslider exists for vanilla PHP, or that the site you linked isn't using Joomla?

Comment: @Michael Petrotta, i viewed the source code from the browser. it seems to be written in php(i don't know joomla but think probably i am not wrong). if my guess is right then there must be a pure php version of yooslider, right?

Comment: u so nice, sir... it just told me to wait for a time period 5sec, 5 min... so i couldn't edit fully. and u responded in the mean time!!! 10q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you linked is definitely Joomla, they didn't bother to remove any of the Joomla fingerprint. The best you are going to be able to do is take the Yooslider apart and fill in the Joomla bits with static content or content from another source. In general a Joomla module uses the framework for connecting to the DB to get some content so it should be fairly easy to make it stand alone if you are good with PHP.

Comment: can u please give me any URL detailing the procedure to convert a Joomla module into pure php? i can't find any useful one.

Comment: There isn't one. Basically you need to find anything in the code that refers to Joomla and remove it or replace it with content.

Comment: that wouldn't be so easy i think... still i may want to have a try.